# Difference between initializer and default initializer list in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

HI, 
I have a question but cannot find the answer for a long time, that is, 
what's difference between the following 2 statements about the parameter 
initialization?

```
class A::A() 
    : a(0), b(0), c(0) 
{ 
}

class A::A() 
{ 
    a = 0 
    b = 0; 
    c = 0; 
}
```

I know there is "direct initialization" and "copy initialization", but I 
don't know what's the other differences and if there is any description 
about the first statement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user692270 I've edited and added a missing colon to your initialization list example.

Comment: Note that the `=` in the second example is neither "direct initialization" nor "copy initialization", but assignment.

Comment: Another question where user692270 accepts @karthik 's answer. Stop using two accounts for upvote-farming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of default initialization list is to initialize the constant variable with in the class.
    Because the constant variable is initialized before the object is initialized.

I provide one sample to explain the difference between these two initializations:

```
 class A
   {
       private:
          const int x;

  };

  A::A():x(5)        //this code works fine
  {

    }

    A::A()       //this code is wrong.const variable is not initialized once object         
   {
    x=5;
    }
```

Comment: It's not just for initializing the constants, but **all** members. And it is obligatory for references as well.

Comment: ... or class-type members and bases without default constructors.

Answer (score 35):

Using the initializer list, the members are created and initialized only once, with the given value.

Using assignment, the members are initialized with a default value, *then* reassigned in the constructor body.

In some cases (constants, references) you can only use initialization lists because

- these must be initialized with a valid value, and
- once they are constructed, reassigning them is illegal.

In other cases, even though assignment is possible, initialization list is still preferable as it avoids extra work (double initialization, which can be costly for some types) and adheres to a common idiom, making your code easier to understand and maintain.

One caveat which is good to know is that the order of initialization of members is defined by their order of declaration, **not** by the order in which they are listed in the initialization list. E.g.

```
class Example {
  int a, b, c;

  Example() : a(1), c(2), b(c) {}
}
```

yields undefined behaviour because `b` is initialized *before* `c`, hence with an undefined value. To avoid confusion and the potential for such subtle bugs, always list members in the initialization list in the same order as they're declared in the class.

This may seem obscure at first, but there is a reason for it. In C++, it is guaranteed that all members of a class are destroyed in exactly the reverse of the order they were created. Now, classes can have multiple constructors, each with its own initialization list, and (unfortunately, one might say) initialization lists can be ordered any way the programmer wants. If the order of the initialization list determined the actual order of initialization, the runtime should somehow maintain data about each object to remember which constructor it was created with, and in what order its members should be destroyed. This would incure runtime overhead, for no obvious benefit, so - in line with the general C++ philosophy of "pay only for what you use" - it was decided that the initialization order is defined by the declaration order once and for all.

Comment: This becomes crucial when initialization is expensive, or when you deal with types that are not default-constructible.

Comment: @MSalters, you are right, maybe I was overly meticulous here. Although I can't help thinking that there must be people out there trying to write code like `C() : aConst(0) { aConst = theRealValue; }` :-)

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is, that in first case the clas members are *initialized* and in the second case they are *assigned*. For non integral types it means, that in the second case you will use `operator=` to assign values to your class members.

Commonly, it's preferred to use first case, because in that case class memebers are initialized *before* the constructor body.

Also, you can't use assignment on several cases, for example, when class member is declared *const*.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [section 10.6 of the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) by Marshall Cline:

> Initialization lists. In fact,
>   constructors should initialize as a
>   rule all member objects in the
>   initialization list. One exception is
>   discussed further down.
>
> Consider the following constructor
>   that initializes member object x_
>   using an initialization list:
>   Fred::Fred() : x_(whatever) { }. The
>   most common benefit of doing this is
>   improved performance. For example, if
>   the expression whatever is the same
>   type as member variable x_, the result
>   of the whatever expression is
>   constructed directly inside x_ — the
>   compiler does not make a separate copy
>   of the object. Even if the types are
>   not the same, the compiler is usually
>   able to do a better job with
>   initialization lists than with
>   assignments.
>
> The other (inefficient) way to build
>   constructors is via assignment, such
>   as: Fred::Fred() { x_ = whatever; }.
>   In this case the expression whatever
>   causes a separate, temporary object to
>   be created, and this temporary object
>   is passed into the x_ object's
>   assignment operator. Then that
>   temporary object is destructed at the
>   ;. That's inefficient.
>
> As if that wasn't bad enough, there's
>   another source of inefficiency when
>   using assignment in a constructor: the
>   member object will get fully
>   constructed by its default
>   constructor, and this might, for
>   example, allocate some default amount
>   of memory or open some default file.
>   All this work could be for naught if
>   the whatever expression and/or
>   assignment operator causes the object
>   to close that file and/or release that
>   memory (e.g., if the default
>   constructor didn't allocate a large
>   enough pool of memory or if it opened
>   the wrong file).
>
> Conclusion: All other things being
>   equal, your code will run faster if
>   you use initialization lists rather
>   than assignment.
>
> Note: There is no performance
>   difference if the type of x_ is some
>   built-in/intrinsic type, such as int
>   or char* or float. But even in these
>   cases, my personal preference is to
>   set those data members in the
>   initialization list rather than via
>   assignment for consistency. Another
>   symmetry argument in favor of using
>   initialization lists even for
>   built-in/intrinsic types: non-static
>   const and non-static reference data
>   members can't be assigned a value in
>   the constructor, so for symmetry it
>   makes sense to initialize everything
>   in the initialization list.
>
> Now for the exceptions. Every rule has
>   exceptions (hmmm; does "every rule has
>   exceptions" have exceptions? reminds
>   me of Gödel's Incompleteness
>   Theorems), and there are a couple of
>   exceptions to the "use initialization
>   lists" rule. Bottom line is to use
>   common sense: if it's cheaper, better,
>   faster, etc. to not use them, then by
>   all means, don't use them. This might
>   happen when your class has two
>   constructors that need to initialize
>   the this object's data members in
>   different orders. Or it might happen
>   when two data members are
>   self-referential. Or when a
>   data-member needs a reference to the
>   this object, and you want to avoid a
>   compiler warning about using the this
>   keyword prior to the { that begins the
>   constructor's body (when your
>   particular compiler happens to issue
>   that particular warning). Or when you
>   need to do an if/throw test on a
>   variable (parameter, global, etc.)
>   prior to using that variable to
>   initialize one of your this members.
>   This list is not exhaustive; please
>   don't write me asking me to add
>   another "Or when...". The point is
>   simply this: use common sense.

Comment: A good answer, to be sure, but maybe a little bit... long.