# A c++ syntax question: class for method

Tags: c++, namespaces

in the code below, it has the following line

```
 base_list(const base_list &tmp) :memory::SqlAlloc()
```

base_list is a method, memory is a namespace, SqlAlloc is a class, so what does it mean when combine them together?

```
class base_list :public memory::SqlAlloc
{
public:
  base_list(const base_list &tmp) :memory::SqlAlloc()
  {
    elements= tmp.elements;
    first= tmp.first;
    last= elements ? tmp.last : &first;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
base_list(const base_list &tmp) :memory::SqlAlloc()
```

Uses `Initializer list` to call constructor of class `SqlAlloc` inside namespace `memory`.

For more information on advantages of using `Initializer List` in C++, See [**this**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6).

Answer (score 2):

It calls the default constructor of the base class `memory::SqlAlloc()`.

```
namespace memory {

class SqlAlloc
{
public:
    SqlAlloc() {} // SqlAlloc's default constructor
};

}

//...

class base_list : public memory::SqlAlloc
{
public:
  // base_list constructor
  base_list(const base_list &tmp) : memory::SqlAlloc()
  {
   // The code after the ":" above and before the "{" brace
   // is the initializer list
    elements= tmp.elements;
    first= tmp.first;
    last= elements ? tmp.last : &first;
  };
```

Consider the following:

```
int main()
{
    base_list bl; // instance of base_list called "bl" is declared.
}
```

When `bl` is created, it calls the constructor of `base_list`. This causes the code in the initializer list of the `base_list` constructor to run. That initializer list has `memory::SqlAlloc()`, which calls `SqlAlloc`'s default constructor. When `SqlAlloc`'s constructor finishes, then the `base_list`'s constructor is run.

Answer (score 1):

base_list is the constructor and it's calling the constructor of the base class (SqlAlloc).

Answer (score 1):

`:memory::SqlAlloc()` calls the base class's default contructor and is as such not required here;

The syntax is called: (base) initializer list, see also [Difference between initializer and default initializer list in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816218/difference-between-initializer-and-default-initializer-list-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

`base_list` inherits from `memory::SqlAlloc`.

The line you ask about is the copy constructor. The `: memory::SqlAlloc()` after is the base class initializer. It calls the constructor of the base class.